# Paillier cryptosystem for verifiable shuffles

Tags: paillier, mixnets, shuffle

I am looking for some algorithm or implementation on Pailler cryptosystem-based verifiable shuffles for mixNet. So far, all the verifiable shuffles and mixNet are available for ElGamal cryptosystems like the Groth method, etc. Does anyone know the implementation done specifically for Paillier encryption? If not, can I use the Elgamal-based verifiable shuffles and mixNet for the inputs being encrypted by the paillier cryptosystem (as it is mentioned in almost every paper that the current design is for ElGamal but you can use it for paillier as well)... would this work correctly or I need a proper algorithm of paillier?